# Find substring and delete parent substring using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a problem with using sed that I can't seem to find a way to resolve. I am needing to find for a substring, then delete a parent substring.

Here are the steps I wanting to achieve:

1. Find `sourceMappingURL=` in the file
2. Delete the parent substring starting at `//# sourceMappingURL` and ending at `.map`

Here is a sample input and output I am expecting:

Input

```
!function(e){var n={};function t(i){if(n[i])return n[i].exports; //more code
//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map
```

Output

```
!function(e){var n={};function t(i){if(n[i])return n[i].exports; //more code
```

The reason I am doing it this way instead of deleting the line that contains the substring is that for some reason for some of the js files it doesn't just delete that line, it deletes the one above.

My command that deletes the line with the substring looks like:

```
find my_folder -type f -name "*.js" | xargs sed -i.bak '/sourceMappingURL=/d'
```

I am not very good with regex, and tried the following but didn't work `(\/\/\# sourceMappingURL){1}(\w.*)(\.map){1}`, `(\/\/#)(\w.*)(map)`  doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak '/^\/\/#[[:blank:]]*sourceMappingURL.*\.map$/d'`. Or `sed -i.bak 's,^//#[[:blank:]]*sourceMappingURL.*\.map,,'`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Feel welcome to post this as the answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I had to sleep it off for the whole week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of

```sh
sed -i.bak '/^\/\/#[[:blank:]]*sourceMappingURL.*\.map$/d'
sed -i.bak 's,^//#[[:blank:]]*sourceMappingURL.*\.map,,'
```

The first `sed` command finds

- `^` - start of string
- `\/\/#` - a `//#` string
- `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `sourceMappingURL`  -  a subtring
- `.*` - any text up to and including
- `\.map` - a `.map` substring at the...
- `$` - end of string

and `d`eletes the line where the match was found.

The second command only deletes the contents of the same line since the action is to `s`ubstitute the match with an empty string (`,` regex delimiter is used to avoid matching `/` chars in the LHS).